# Prestashop: url to get parents categories

Tags: rest, prestashop

I use this url to get the categories: http://192.168.1.26/prestashop/api/categories
but this link return all the categories.
how can i get the  parents categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found it , this is how i did
http://192.168.1.26/prestashop/api/categories/?display=full&filter[id_parent]=[]

in the url you filter ,the categories that has no parent